# copyTo range does not copy drawings?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When I use copyTo to copy an entire sheet, drawings get copied but I don't want to copy the entire sheet so I tried to use copyTo on a range but drawings do not get copied. Anyone know if this is expected behavior or a bug? For example if a drawing is in A4 ...

```
function test() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var test1 = ss.getSheetByName("test1");
var test2 = ss.getSheetByName("test2");

// this does not copy drawing to sheet test2

var rangeToCopy = test1.getRange(1,1,5,1);
rangeToCopy.copyTo(test2.getRange(1,1));

// this copies drawing to new sheet Copy of test1

test1.copyTo(ss);

}
```

I realize there are two copyTo's, one for sheets and one for ranges, just would have expected they both should copy drawings.

Answer (score 0):

no, it doesnt copy drawings. a big part of it is that drawings do not sit on a given cell or range.

you can confirm this by inserting rows above the drawing. sometimes google shifts the drawing down and sometimes doesnt, so it's not tied to specific rows, at least not strictly.

you can also confirm that copying ranges manually with the web interface also doesnt copy the drawings.

**one solution** is to convert the drawing to an image and host it somewhere (like a google sites cabinet with public access) and use cell formula `=IMAGE("http://path.to.image.png")' which will get copied.

**another way** if you must use drawings, is to copy the entire sheet into a new sheet, then manually copy the ranges that you didnt want to overwrite from your destination sheet, then delete the original destination sheet and rename the new sheet with the destination name.

Comment: Thanks for reply, the drawings all contain assignments to scripts so using =IMAGE will not work in this case. As far as the other workaround, when I delete the original  sheet, I seem to remember that will break formula references to it in other sheets and replace the deleted sheet name with #Ref in the formulas, no?

Comment: Gosh, I have not looked at using =IMAGE in so long I did not realize you can now assign scripts to it as well as you pointed out - or perhaps one always could and I just overlooked it. I will give that a try, thanks.

Comment: Aw, I am getting mixed up with inserting images which you can assign scripts to but like drawings do not get copied and using =IMAGE which you can't assign scripts to.

So I am back to your other solution of copying and deleting sheet. I supposed I could write a script to do a search and replace on #Ref but given the vast number of sheets and cells that would need to be iterated over that seems like overkill.

Comment: yes. one is a cell formula while the other is an inserted object on top of the cells. youve got the cake but you cant eat it :)